# Exposed GCP API keys warning received eventhough i restricted the api key to android specific app

Tags: android, security, mobile, api-key, android-security

I received a warning for Exposed GCP API keys , event if i restricted my api key to android application giving the package name and SHA-1 signing-certificate fingerprint.

Do you know how to get rid of this warning?

I read the GCP best practices and they say it is ok to make the restrictions to android application giving the package name and SHA-1 signing-certificate fingerprint, but the warning is still there.

I am using the maps static api like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + coordinates +"&zoom=13&markers=" + coordinates + "&size=" + width + "x" + height + "&sensor=false" + "&scale=" + scale+"&key="+apiKey;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know how to get rid of this warning?

Probably its because you have the GCP API key hard-coded in your code.

## How to hide the API key

> Do you know how to get rid of this warning?

Sometime ago I wrote a blog post entitled [How to Extract an API Key from a Mobile App by Static Binary Analysis](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-extract-an-api-key-from-a-mobile-app-with-static-binary-analysis), where I show several ways that developers use to store the API key in their mobile app, and how they can be extracted by reverse engineering the APK:

> we will see how to grab that API key from your mobile app by reverse engineering the binary in an effective and quick way with an open source tool. Once we see how easy it can be done, we will realize that it is even achievable by non-developers.

For this article I created the repository [android-hide-secrets](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets), and I will use it to show you how to hide the API key, where we will make use of native C++ code to store the API key, by leveraging the [JNI interface](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni) which uses [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk) under the hood.

### Adding the cpp folder to your app

Copy [this folder](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets/blob/ed0217325d42be480a15c003fae9f201ee0f3f88/app/src/main/cpp) to the main folder of your app, and you should end up with it at`app/src/main/cpp`.

Now copy the file [api_key.h.example](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets/blob/master/app/src/main/cpp/api_key.h.example) to `api_key.h`. Afterwards edit the file and add the API key for GPC where it says `"place-the-api-key-here"`.

> **NOTE**: the file `api_key.h` will not be tracked by your repository, once its listed to be ignored by git in the [app/src/main/cpp/.gitignore](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets/blob/ed0217325d42be480a15c003fae9f201ee0f3f88/app/src/main/cpp/.gitignore).

### Configure Gradle

Open your `app/build.gradle` and add [this code](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets/blob/ed0217325d42be480a15c003fae9f201ee0f3f88/app/build.gradle#L15-L19):

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cppFlags ""
    }
}
```

### Retrieve the API Key at Run-Time

In order to be able to get the GPC API during run-time, just add [this code](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets/blob/ed0217325d42be480a15c003fae9f201ee0f3f88/app/src/main/java/com/criticalblue/androidhidesecrets/MainActivity.java#L16-L19) to your class:

```java
    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }
```

and also [this code](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets/blob/ed0217325d42be480a15c003fae9f201ee0f3f88/app/src/main/java/com/criticalblue/androidhidesecrets/MainActivity.java#L37-L41):

```java
    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    public native String stringFromJNI();
```

Then when you need the API key just retrieve it like its done [here](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets/blob/ed0217325d42be480a15c003fae9f201ee0f3f88/app/src/main/java/com/criticalblue/androidhidesecrets/MainActivity.java#L33):

```java
renderApiKeyForView(R.id.jni_value, stringFromJNI());
```

While in this demo app I am just rendering the API key in a view, in a production app you would use `stringFromJNI()` to add the API key to the request header.

## Conclusion

As I mentioned in the blog post, when an API key is hidden with this technique its not impossible to retrieve the API key with reverse engineering, but is pretty hard once guess work is necessary to associate the strings returned from parsing the binary.

I believe that after you apply this technique the warning for Exposed GCP API keys will go away. Please let me know how it went.

## WARNING

While this technique gives you some level of protection against reverse engineering and will solve your warning issue, it will not deter an attacker from grabbing an API key hidden in your app by performing a MitM attack as I explain in this other blog post, entitled [Steal that API Key with a Man in the Middle Attack](https://blog.approov.io/steal-that-api-key-with-a-man-in-the-middle-attack):

> So, in this article you will learn how to setup and run a MitM attack to intercept https traffic in a mobile device under your control, so that you can steal the API key. Finally, you will see at a high level how MitM attacks can be mitigated.